# Mat spinner is not shown

Tags: angular, authentication, spinner

I want to show a spinner when log in is processed.

#### login.component.ts:

```
constructor(public spinner: SpinnerComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.showSpinner = false;
  }

  login() {
    this.spinner.showSpinner = true;
    this.userService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(loginResponse => {
      ...
      this.spinner.showSpinner = false;
    });
  }
```

#### spinner.component.ts:

```
export class SpinnerComponent {

  @Input()
  showSpinner;

  constructor() { }
}
```

#### spinner.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="showSpinner">
    <mat-spinner [mode]="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

It seems that communication between login component and spinner component to set the showSpinner value is not correct.

Any idea about how to show the spinner?

Comment: can you show me the code of login.component.html?

Comment: why are you injecting the component as if it was a service ? constructor(public spinner: SpinnerComponent)

Comment: It 's wrong to inject a component like this constructor(public spinner: SpinnerComponent) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add spinner component to login html like this

*login.component.html*

```
<app-spinner [showSpinner]="showSpinner"></app-spinner>
```

*login.component.ts:*

```
  public showSpinner:bollean=false; 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.showSpinner = false;
  }

  login() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.userService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(loginResponse => {
      ...
      this.showSpinner = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. So do I need to add the app-spinner to the html of all the components that I would like to show the spinner? Is there another way like adding it to the app.component.html?

Comment: yes you can create a service and toggle the state of the `showSpinner` from that service , I will update my  answer and include this point  @RAL

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **@Input()** with **showSpinner** property

just create showspinner as boolean like,

```
showSpinner: boolean;
```

**@Input()** decorator means you are passing value by component decorator

Answer (score 0):

login.component.ts

```
isWaiting: boolean = false;
constructor() { 
}
ngOnInit() { 
}

login() {
  this.isWaiting = true;
  this.userService.login(this.username, 
    this.password).subscribe(loginResponse => {
    ...
    this.isWaiting = false;
  });
}
```

in html

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isWaiting" [mode]="'indeterminate'"> 
</mat-spinner>
```